# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

I tried to fix this request for hours with no success so I'm hoping that you guys can help me find what's wrong:

```
SELECT ((
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM (
        SELECT REPLACE(source_name, "+", "") AS name
        FROM events
        WHERE source_name!=""
        UNION
        SELECT REPLACE(target_name, "+", "") AS name
        FROM events
        WHERE target_name!=""
    )
) AS player_name,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM events
    WHERE source_name=player_name AND event_name="beforePlayerBan"
) as nbr_bans,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM events
    WHERE source_name=player_name AND event_name="beforePlayerKick"
) as nbr_kicks,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM events
    WHERE
        (source_name=player_name OR target_name=player_name)
        AND event_name="afterBattleStarted"
) as nbr_battles,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM events
    WHERE source_name=player_name AND result=0
) as nbr_wins,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM events
    WHERE target_name=player_name AND result=0
) as nbr_defeats,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM events
    WHERE (source_name=player_name OR target_name=player_name) AND result=1
) as nbr_ties,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM events
    WHERE (source_name=player_name OR target_name=player_name) AND result=2
) as nbr_forfeits
```

the error is SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias which is weird since I did give every table its own alias

Comment: Start by breaking down the query by each subquery..  then to each column.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your first sub-query is missing an alias:

```
SELECT ((
       SELECT DISTINCT *
       FROM (
              SELECT REPLACE(source_name, "+", "") AS name
              FROM events
              WHERE source_name!=""
              UNION
              SELECT REPLACE(target_name, "+", "") AS name
              FROM events
              WHERE target_name!=""
    )  myMissingAlias -- alias needed here
) AS player_name,
```

Plus unless you did not post the full query, I think you might be missing a final `)`